# How set for collision with other balls while ball is growing?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to stop grooving of ball and drop to bottom of the stage when it's hit to the other balls.But I can't.
I tried set distance but it's not worked.

I add a picture of the game

And my code

Enemy balls(green) touch each other fine.But not touch circle make by the mouse.Balls touch to black balls but not seeing touched massage.The touch message appear only when touch the mouse arrow.

```
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import Ball;
import Tekno;

var nSpeedX:Number;
var nSpeedY:Number;

var nStageWidth:Number = 500;
var nStageHeight:Number = 400;

var NSpeedX:Number;
var NSpeedY:Number;




var the_kall:kall;      //Big ball ( make by player)
var mcKall:boru;       //Red ball 
var drawing:Boolean=false;
var nNumBalls:Number = 2;
var initX:Number=0.0;
var initY:Number=0.0;
var topisler:Number=0;



var pressed:Boolean=false;


var MCBallA:MovieClip;
var MCBallB:MovieClip;




var zamzam:Boolean=false;


var kao:Number=10;
var kao2:Number=10;





var mcBallContainer:MovieClip;
var mcfakContainer:MovieClip;
var mcKallCont:MovieClip;



stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mousePressed);
function mousePressed(e:MouseEvent) {

    zamzam=true;




}


  //*********   Create red ball if mouse press up

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mousebrk);
function mousebrk(e:MouseEvent) {

    zamzam=false;
    topisler +=1;
    kao =1;
    kao2 =1;

    mcKallCont = new MovieClip () ;
            stage.addChild(mcKallCont);

    mcKall = new boru ();
    mcKallCont.x =the_kall.x ;
    mcKallCont.y = the_kall.y;
    mcKall.width =the_kall.width;
    mcKall.height =the_kall.height;
    mcKallCont.addChild ( mcKall );

    //for ( var p = 0; p < mcKallCont.numChildren; p++ ) 

    //var mcKall1:* = mcKallCont.getChildAt( p );




}





//*********   Create big ball

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
 function Update(e:Event) {


     if(zamzam==true){ //********check if mouse pressed

         the_kall = new kall();
            the_kall.x=mouseX;
            the_kall.y=mouseY;
            the_kall.width =kao;
            the_kall.height =kao2;
            addChild(the_kall);


          kao +=1;
           kao2 +=1;
    ///////////


     }





 }








//**************Drag

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoved);
function mouseMoved(e:MouseEvent) {
    if (drawing) {
                the_kall.x=mouseX;
                the_kall.y=mouseY;
            }
}











        //************Add black balls and check collision


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BallCollision);
function BallCollision(oly:Event) {

mcBallContainer = new MovieClip ( ) ;
            mcBallContainer.x = mcBallContainer.y = 0;
            stage.addChild(mcBallContainer);

            this.addEventListener ( Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler );

            for ( var i = 0; i < nNumBalls; i++ )
            {
                var mcBall:Ball = new Ball ( Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 12 ) - 4 ), Math.floor ( ( Math.random() * 12 ) - 4 ) );
                mcBall.x = Math.random() * nStageWidth;
                mcBall.y = Math.random() * nStageHeight;
                mcBallContainer.addChild ( mcBall );
            }
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,BallCollision);
        }

function enterFrameHandler(oly:Event) {

    for ( var i = 0; i < mcBallContainer.numChildren; i++ )
            {
                var mcBall1:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( i );

                for ( var j = i + 1; j < mcBallContainer.numChildren; j++ )
                {
                    var mcBall2:* = mcBallContainer.getChildAt( j );

                    var nDistX:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.x - mcBall2.x );
                    var nDistY:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.y - mcBall2.y );
                    var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );


                    //***********I Tried big ball vs black ball
                    var sDistx:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.x - the_kall.x );
                    var sDisty:Number = Math.abs ( mcBall1.y - the_kall.y );
                    var nsistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( sDistx * sDistx + sDisty * sDisty );



                    if ( nsistance < 20 )
                    {
                        touch.text="balls are touch";
                    }




                    if ( nDistance < 20 )
                    {
                        solveBalls ( mcBall1, mcBall2 ); //*****if black balls touch each other
                    }


                }
            }
             onda.text=String(nsistance);



        }

          function solveBalls ( MCBallA:MovieClip, MCBallB:MovieClip ) : void
        {
            var nX1:Number = MCBallA.x;
            var nY1:Number = MCBallA.y;
            var nDistX:Number = MCBallB.x - nX1;
            var nDistY:Number = MCBallB.y - nY1;

            var nDistance:Number = Math.sqrt ( nDistX * nDistX + nDistY * nDistY );
            var nRadiusA:Number = MCBallA.width/2;
            var nRadiusB:Number = MCBallB.width/2;
            //var nRadius:Number = 10;

            var nNormalX:Number = nDistX/nDistance;
            var nNormalY:Number = nDistY/nDistance;

            var nMidpointX:Number = ( nX1 + MCBallB.x )/2;
            var nMidpointY:Number = ( nY1 + MCBallB.y )/2;

            MCBallA.x = nMidpointX - nNormalX * nRadiusA;
            MCBallA.y = nMidpointY - nNormalY * nRadiusA;
            MCBallB.x = nMidpointX + nNormalX * nRadiusB;
            MCBallB.y = nMidpointY + nNormalY * nRadiusB;

            var nVector:Number = ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedX - MCBallB.nSpeedX ) * nNormalX )+ ( ( MCBallA.nSpeedY - MCBallB.nSpeedY ) * nNormalY );
            var nVelX:Number = nVector * nNormalX;
            var nVelY:Number = nVector * nNormalY;

            MCBallA.nSpeedX -= nVelX;
            MCBallA.nSpeedY -= nVelY;
            MCBallB.nSpeedX += nVelX;
            MCBallB.nSpeedY += nVelY;
        }



//just test blue ball

/*                  stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,test);
function test(oly:Event) {


if(the_kall.hitTestObject(keko)){
        zacma.text="llj"; 
        }
}*/






stop();
```

Comment: I have a lot of work today but I want to throw out a reference to Box2D http://www.box2dflash.org/

Comment: In your code which var means green ball and which var is the big ball? What line ties to check their collsions  (green ball vs big ball)?

Comment: I updated message.Balls touch to black balls but not seeing touched massage.The touch message appear only when touch the mouse arrow.

Comment: @quantomworks Actually I have project works exactly like that,and maked by Box2D.But it's have lot of mini class file and I can't change some properties.