# How to addchild for this code?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm generally not use addchild. I found that code and I tried to create a circle when mouse pressed and, I tried collision other balls.
So I can create ball by the mouse but I didn't collide with other balls.

```
import flash.geom.Point;

var NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES:Number = 2;
var NUMKEKKO:Number = 1;

var circle_array:Array;
var boru_array:Array;
var vector_array:Array;
var mass_array:Array;
var mouseuo:Boolean=false;

var the_kall:kall;      //Big ball ( make by player)
var mcKall:boru; 
var barz:circle;//
var drag:Boolean=false;
var mcKallCont:MovieClip;
    var kao:Number=10;
    var kao2:Number=10;
    var topisler:Number=2;

    var gonzo:Number=0;
    var topyap:Boolean=true;









//stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, init); 
//function init(e:Event){
function init(){    

if(topyap==true){
    circle_array = new Array();
    vector_array = new Array();
    mass_array = new Array();
    boru_array = new Array();




    for(var i:Number = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; i++){

        circle_array[i] = new circle();

        circle_array[i].width = 55;// circle_array[i].width = (Math.random() * 50);
        circle_array[i].height = circle_array[i].width;

        circle_array[i].x = (circle_array[i].width/2) + (Math.random() * (550 - circle_array[i].width*(3/2)));
        circle_array[i].y = (circle_array[i].height/2) + (Math.random() * (400 - circle_array[i].height*(3/2)));






        var new_color:uint = 0x000077 * Math.random();
        new_color += 0x000088;

        switch(i%3){
            case 0:
                new_color = new_color << 16;
                break;
            case 1:
                new_color = new_color << 8;
                break;
        }







        //new_color = new_color << 16;
        var myColor:ColorTransform = this.transform.colorTransform;
        myColor.color = new_color;
        circle_array[i].inner.transform.colorTransform = myColor;

        addChild(circle_array[i]);

        circle_array[i].id = i;

        vector_array[i] = new Array(Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10);
        mass_array[i] = circle_array[i].width * 0.10;
    }


}   


topyap=false;





















    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, circle_update); 








}





function circle_update(e:Event){

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; i++){
        circle_array[i].x += vector_array[i][0];
        circle_array[i].y += vector_array[i][1];

        //bounding wall collisions
        if(circle_array[i].x + (circle_array[i].width * 0.50) >= 550){ vector_array[circle_array[i].id][0] *= -1; circle_array[i].x = 550 - circle_array[i].width * 0.50; }
        if(circle_array[i].x - (circle_array[i].width * 0.50) <= 0){ vector_array[circle_array[i].id][0] *= -1;  circle_array[i].x = circle_array[i].width * 0.50; }

        if(circle_array[i].y + (circle_array[i].width * 0.50) >= 400){ vector_array[circle_array[i].id][1] *= -1; circle_array[i].y = 400 - circle_array[i].height * 0.50;  }
        if(circle_array[i].y - (circle_array[i].width * 0.50) <= 0){ vector_array[circle_array[i].id][1] *= -1; circle_array[i].y = circle_array[i].height * 0.50;   }


    }







    //ball to ball collisions
    for(var g:Number = 0; g < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; g++){
        var g_pos:Point = new Point(circle_array[g].x, circle_array[g].y)
        for(var k:Number = g + 1; k < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; k++){
            var dist = Point.distance(g_pos, new Point(circle_array[k].x, circle_array[k].y));
            if( dist < ((circle_array[g].width * 0.50) + (circle_array[k].width * 0.50)) ){
                //they're colliding!
                //elastic response
                var mass1:Number = mass_array[g];
                var mass2:Number = mass_array[k];
                var mass_sum = mass1 + mass2;
                var velX1:Number = vector_array[g][0];
                var velX2:Number = vector_array[k][0];
                var velY1:Number = vector_array[g][1];
                var velY2:Number = vector_array[k][1];

                var new_velX1 = (velX1 * (mass1 - mass2) + (2 * mass2 * velX2)) / mass_sum;
                var new_velX2 = (velX2 * (mass2 - mass1) + (2 * mass1 * velX1)) / mass_sum;
                var new_velY1 = (velY1 * (mass1 - mass2) + (2 * mass2 * velY2)) / mass_sum;
                var new_velY2 = (velY2 * (mass2 - mass1) + (2 * mass1 * velY1)) / mass_sum;

                vector_array[g][0] = new_velX1;
                vector_array[k][0] = new_velX2;
                vector_array[g][1] = new_velY1;
                vector_array[k][1] = new_velY2;

                circle_array[g].x += new_velX1;
                circle_array[g].y += new_velY1;
                circle_array[k].x += new_velX2;
                circle_array[k].y += new_velY2;
            }
        }



    }
    gonzo=dist;








    //Kall to ball collisions
    for(var s:Number = 0; s < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; s++){
        var t_pos:Point = new Point(the_kall.x, the_kall.y)
        for(var t:Number = s + 1; t < NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES; t++){
            var distf = Point.distance(t_pos, new Point(circle_array[t].x, circle_array[t].y));
            if( distf < ((the_kall.width * 0.50) + (circle_array[t].width * 0.50)) )
            {
                dmm.text = "touched";

            //elastic response
            kao +=0;
           kao2 +=0;

                drag=false;
                mouseuo=false;



            }
            }
            } 







}



init();




















































stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mousePressed);
function mousePressed(e:MouseEvent) {
    the_kall = new kall();
            the_kall.x=mouseX;
            the_kall.y=mouseY;

            addChild(the_kall) 
    drag=true;
    mouseuo=true;

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mousebrk)



}












stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);

 function Update(e:Event) {


    if(drag==true){


            the_kall.width =kao;
            the_kall.height =kao2;
            kao ++;
           kao2 ++;

     }


     if(drag==false){

    removeChild(the_kall)

     }


      if(drag==false && mouseuo==true){


        mcKallCont = new MovieClip () ;
            stage.addChild(mcKallCont);

    mcKall = new boru ();
    mcKallCont.x =the_kall.x ;
    mcKallCont.y = the_kall.y;
    mcKall.width =the_kall.width;
    mcKall.height =the_kall.height;
    mcKallCont.addChild ( mcKall );
    mouseuo=false;



        NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES +=1;
        topisler +=1;

     removeChild(the_kall)

     }

}






















stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mousebrk);
function mousebrk(e:MouseEvent) {

    drag=false;


    kao =1;
    kao2 =1;






    //for ( var p = 0; p < mcKallCont.numChildren; p++ ) 

    //var mcKall1:* = mcKallCont.getChildAt( p );




}









stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoved);
function mouseMoved(e:MouseEvent) {
    if(drag==true){


    the_kall.x=mouseX;
    the_kall.y=mouseY;

                }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How set for collision with other balls while ball is growing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44465799/how-set-for-collision-with-other-balls-while-ball-is-growing)

Comment: I'm sorry yes it's could be.But I'll almost have to the solution.I still work on code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `addChild` you are only adding the newly created circle to the stage so that it will be drawn. You will also need to couple it to the logic that handles the ball collisions.

The variable `NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES` will need to be updated to represent the new number of circles. You will also need to add the new circle (and all its values needed in the `circle_update` function) to the `circle_array` array so that the circle's position will be updated each frame. This update is executed in the `circle_update` function. Thus, replace the part of your code where you create `mcKall` with this:

```
if(drag==false && mouseuo==true){
   var i:Number = NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES;
   NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES+=1;

   circle_array[i] = new circle();
   circle_array[i].width = the_kall.width;
   circle_array[i].height = circle_array[i].width;
   circle_array[i].x = the_kall.x;
   circle_array[i].y = the_kall.y;

   var myColor:ColorTransform = this.transform.colorTransform;
   myColor.color = 0x000077 * Math.random() + 0x000088;
   circle_array[i].inner.transform.colorTransform = myColor;
   addChild(circle_array[i]);

   circle_array[i].id = i;
   vector_array[i] = new Array(0,0);
   mass_array[i] = circle_array[i].width * 0.10;

   removeChild(the_kall)
}
```

For future reference, please make sure to post code that is readable. That includes formatting the code and naming your variables so that it makes sense. Variable names like `zamzam` make it harder for other people to help you, because it's harder for them to understand your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and notice.So we know to how many balls will appear on the screen.But what we don't know how many ball will do make by the player.Should I write new array ? Can you give a example please ?

Comment: What do you mean, "put away the ball from other"?

Comment: You have a loop that checks for collisions between all the balls that are stored in the `circle_array`array. And then you have a loop that checks between collisions between the `circle_array` and the player-made `the_kall`. It would suffice if you stored the player-made ball into the `circle_array` as well, as I stated in my answer. Then you don't have to check for `the_kall`specifically. They are all balls, so the same logic can apply. Keep in mind that you'd have to increase  `NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES` to adjust the range the `for`-loop covers.

Comment: I think I didn't make it.When I try to increase to NUMBER_OF_CIRCLES all ball stop on the screen.

Comment: I just tried and nothing to show ! Actually just increase NUMBER OF CIRCLES and,I don't know how increase to number for var.I changed to kall to ball updated original message.

Comment: Let me repeat it once more: you just need to store the new ball in `circle_array` and not in `the_kall` or `mc_kall`. I added code to show this to the answer.

Comment: @jeans Thank you.I understand now.But  if player's ball (call) collision to another ball while it's growing,then it's need to disappear.But it's disappear to only one ball.I set 2 the NUMBER OF CIRCLES to begin but I  have only one ball collision.It's not collide with other ball (Red).How can I collide for other circle ? Here is ss link.https://s2.postimg.org/5t3v9mhdl/bandicam-2017-06-13-17-40-36-110.gif

Comment: That's because the ball is not added to `circle_array` while it is growing. You can add it to `circle_array` instead of putting it into `the_kall`, but you'll need to consider a lot of edge cases (like what happens when there is a collision - is the growing interrupted? Does the growing ball move?). I suggest you try to understand why the code I posted above does what it does, because the same solution applies to your new problem.

Comment: So what if I want to system ball's disappear and lose score when colliding to player ball's.But stay same size when colliding other player's ball.I mean like this http://william.hoza.us/bounce/# Do I need a another circle array or new array ?

Comment: Keep all your balls in `circle_array`. That keeps the physics logic clean. For each ball, you can also store if it is currently being made by the player and change the score accordingly when two balls collide.